# ConfigurationSectionCollection contains many system names besides my custom section

Tags: .net, app-config, configuration-files, configurationmanager, custom-configuration

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="MySection" type="MyApp.MySectionClass, MyApp"/>
    </configSections>

    <MySection name="SomeName" data_type="SomeDataType" file_name="file">
        <CollectionName>
          <add name="name1" param="-10" ping="3"/>
          <add name="name1" param="-10" ping="5"/>
          <add name="name2" param="-10" ping="3" param2="0.3" param3="0.2"/>
        </CollectionName>
    </MySection >

</configuration>
```

Here is the code where i try just to have a list of my names of sections in my config file:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = "path\\app.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSectionCollection section_collection = config.Sections;

foreach (string key in section_collection.Keys) Console.WriteLine(key);
```

Here what i get as a result:

```
system.data.sqlclient
connectionStrings
system.webServer
system.data.dataset
satelliteassemblies
mscorlib
startup
runtime
appSettings
system.data.odbc
system.data
configProtectedData
system.codedom
uri
system.runtime.remoting
assemblyBinding
windows
system.data.oracleclient
MySection
system.windows.forms
system.diagnostics
system.data.oledb
```

As you can see there is my section name, but also a lot of other namespaces. Why does it happen? How can i get only my custom sections from app.config?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a good way:**

```
 var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MySection");
    if (section != null)
    {
        var adds= (section as MySectionClass).CollectionName;
        Console.WriteLine(adds.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < adds.Count; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know sections' names and number of them beforehand. That's why i wanted to iterate over the section collection.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround was suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a907495a-a4c9-41ff-80e0-ae4c24e04ee5/configurationsectioncollection-contains-many-system-names-besides-my-custom-section?forum=clr#8169bd0a-8c58-4b7e-9ad1-54d35b66bde0)

```
IEnumerable<MySectionClass> section_collection = config.Sections.OfType<MySectionClass>();
```